# How to copy and overwrite exiting folder and files inside it if exist using power script

Tags: powershell

I am trying to copy folder and its sub folder which has some files in it.
For example my `folder1` contains folders like `abc` , `xyx` and again inside this folder I have files.
I want to copy the full folder such as `folder1` and paste it in the destination, if it exists then replace all the files in it. I am using the below commands.

My problem is if I run this script multiple times it is creating subfolders inside subfolder, like inside `abc` it is again creating `abc` which I do not want.

```
$sourceFolder='C:\abc\foder1'
$destFolder='c:\Test\folder1'

Get-ChildItem $sourceFolder | ForEach-Object `
{
    $destFullPath = Join-Path $destFolder ($_.BaseName + $_.Extension)
    Copy-Item -Path $_.FullName -Destination $destFullPath  -Force  -Recurse 
}
```

Comment: Your text says `folder1` contains `abc,xyz`, in your code it's vice versa?

Comment: could you please help me with code .. I did not get how to get this done.  I know something is creating multiple folder and files if I run it many times.

Comment: This is a known issue of Copy-Item. See here for details https://superuser.com/questions/544520/how-can-i-copy-a-directory-overwriting-its-contents-if-it-exists-using-powershe

Comment: @Ashis: The linked question is essentially the same and has an answer that should work for you.